# javascript polling at given time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following function is being called at every 10 second.

```
function getData()
    {      
        $.ajax({
              url       : "refresh.php",
              type      : "POST",
              data      : {"id" : id},            
              success   : function(data) {
                 $(".show").html(data);
              }
          });
    }
        $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval("getData()",50000);//Polls in every 50 sec
    });
```

What I want is: when page is loaded, `getData()` should be called instantly, after that each call should be at given interval i.e. 50second

how to do this?

Comment: "getData()" is string, it should be setInterval(getData,50000)

Comment: @nasaorc it should be, but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a manual call to `getData()` in the dom ready handler

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "refresh.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "id": id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(".show").html(data);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("getData()", 50000); //Polls in every 50 sec
    getData(); //invoke on page load
});
```

Comment: thanks dude. Here `getData()` should be before `setInterval()` or my understanding is wrong. bcoz we want first function to be called and then put the interval

Answer (score 1):

Call the function from the ready event.

Also, use the function reference in the `setInterval` call rather than a string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(getData,50000);
  getData();
});
```